# output data of a .json file into php file in html table

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

guys, I would like to solve this I been stuck 2days on it, so i want to put in the table 2 value the one who say rank: 9074838 and the one in top 1 , value: 33
I have a .json file named: greenz_lewis.json who look like this

```
      {
        "accountId": "6df47486-86d6-4b4b-a5e7-4c6b1b8c9322",
        "user": "greenz_lewis",
        "stats": {
                 "p2": {
                      "score": {
                          "label": "Score",
                          "category": "General",
                          "rank": 9074838,
                          },
                       "top1": {
                          "label": "Wins",
                          "value": "33",
                            }
                    }
             }
```

and I have my PHP file who looks like this

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
        header("location: error.php");    
    }
    else {
        // Makes it easier to read
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   }

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body class="is-preload">
      <section id="main" class="wrapper">
          <div class="inner">
              <table id="stats1">
                    <th>solo wins</th>                  
                    <th>duos wins</th>
                    <th>squad wins</th>
                    <th>total killz</th>
            </table>
  <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){ 

                $.ajax({
                    url:'userstats/<?=$_SESSION['username'] ?>.json',
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data){
                        $(data.stats).each(function(index,value){
                            var record="<tr><td>"+(top1)+
                                "</td><td>"+top1.label+"</td><td>"+
                                 top1.value+"</td>"
                                "</td></tr>";
                                $("table").append(record);
                                });
                            }
                        });
                });
        </script>
    </div>
    </section>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

so it doesn't work I have tried like 5 different ways this is the closest one

Comment: Suggest you start by logging the arguments of `each` callback to console so you can inspect what they are and react accordingly. Can't just make up variables like `top1` and expect them to be defined out of thin air

Comment: and how can i  log the arguments of each callback to console

Comment: Use `console.log(someVariable)` and open browser dev tools console (F12) to inspect output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice some issues with your JSON file. You have extra commas and a missing bracket.

Here is a version without structure issues.

```
{
    "accountId": "6df47486-86d6-4b4b-a5e7-4c6b1b8c9322",
    "user": "greenz_lewis",
    "stats": {
        "p2": {
            "score": {
                "label": "Score",
                "category": "General",
                "rank": 9074838
            },
            "top1": {
                "label": "Wins",
                "value": "33"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I would suggest doing baby steps.

## Get the content of the file

First, get the content of the file (whatever the extension is). You can reach this objective using the [`file_get_contents` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for instance.

```php
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("file.json");

var_dump($content);
```

would give

```
string(258) "{
    "accountId": "6df47486-86d6-4b4b-a5e7-4c6b1b8c9322",
    "user": "greenz_lewis",
    "stats": {
        "p2": {
            "score": {
                "label": "Score",
                "category": "General",
                "rank": 9074838
            },
            "top1": {
                "label": "Wins",
                "value": "33"
            }
        }
    }
}
"
```

### Parse the content of the JSON file

Then, parse the `string` into an array. You may want to use [`json_decode` function](https://www.php.net/json_decode) for that.

```php
<?php

$decoded = json_decode($content, true);

var_dump($decoded);
```

would give

```
array(3) {
  ["accountId"]=>
  string(36) "6df47486-86d6-4b4b-a5e7-4c6b1b8c9322"
  ["user"]=>
  string(12) "greenz_lewis"
  ["stats"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["p2"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["score"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(5) "Score"
        ["category"]=>
        string(7) "General"
        ["rank"]=>
        int(9074838)
      }
      ["top1"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(4) "Wins"
        ["value"]=>
        string(2) "33"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Create the table items

Next, let's create the table items.

```php
<tr>
<td><?= $decoded['stats']['p2']['score']['rank']; ?></td>
<td><?= $decoded['stats']['p2']['top1']['value']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

would give

```
<tr>
<td>9074838</td>
<td>33</td>
</tr>
```

### Gather everything

```php
<?php

$content = file_get_contents('foo.json');

if (! $content) {
    // File doesn't exists
}

$decoded = json_decode($content, true);
if (! $decoded) {
    // Unable to parse JSON
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Player</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?= $decoded['stats']['p2']['score']['rank']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $decoded['stats']['p2']['top1']['value']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <table>
  </body>
</html>
```

would give

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Player</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9074838</td>
        <td>33</td>
      </tr>
    <table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: result]

I let you the joy to handle the redirection and handling errors in case the file doesn't exist or decoding JSON is failing.

### Concerns

Be careful about how you write your table. The table you started has four columns but you wanted to *append* two values.

You are using Ajax but you don't need. The job of retrieving the content of a file can be done server-side.

Again, be careful about how you structure your JSON file.

Comment: Needing or not needing ajax is very subjective. One big advantage is faster initial page loads

Comment: this answer was the most helpful in my whole lifetime, thank you so much it worked right away the way I wanted it to work and your explanations were great I hope it will help someone in a similar problem, it helped me see it in a new way.